# Rad studio c++ distribute dll

Tags: c++, dll, dll-injection, c++builder-2010

hey guys actually it might be simple problem but i couldnt figure it out(sorry for my english btw). Here is my question. I have dll coded with Rad Studio c++ ide. I want to inject it in a process on another computer which has not installed rad studio. It gives me 1st picture error. 2nd and 3rd pictures are my setting on debug mode.

[image: 1st]

[image: 2nd Runtime settings]
[image: 3rd Linker settings]

Thx and best regards.

Comment: It is clear that your DLL is 32bit and configured to be self-contained, but we can't help you without knowing how you are doing the injection in the first place (there are several different ways to inject a DLL), if the target process is 32bit or 64bit (the DLL can only be injected in 32bit processes), if the DLL has any external dependencies that you are not deploying, etc.  Please provide more info.

Comment: Im using Extreme injector, Target process is 32 bit for sure. Im including vcl.h stdio.h ws32... and PatternFind.h(its library for pattern scan). I put borlandmm.dll within same dll folder. I used ansistring too(maybe this is the problem about memmgr.lib)